# Classifications of projective representations of $SO(N)$ and $SO(N)\times Z_2^T$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, group-cohomology

This question is motivated by some physics questions: what are the classifications of projective representations of groups $SO(N)$ and $SO(N)\times Z_2^T$? This is equivalent to asking what are $H^2(SO(N),U(1))$ and $H^2(SO(N)\times Z_2^T,U(1))$. Here $Z_2^T$ is a group with two elements, identity $1$ and $g$, such that $g^2=1$ and the action of $g$ is anti-unitary. That is, $g$ can always be decomposed into a product of a unitary action and complex conjugation.

It is known that $SO(N)$ has spinor representations, so I think the classification of projective representations of $SO(N)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Although $SO(2N)$ seems to have two spinor representations, I believe they correspond to the same projective representation. For example, $SO(4)=\frac{SU(2)\times SU(2)}{Z_2}$. $SO(4)$ seems to have two spinor representations, $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ and $(0,\frac{1}{2})$, but they differ from each other by $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, which is a linear representation of $SO(4)$. I think this should also work for the two spinor representations for $SO(6)=SU(4)/Z_2$. $SO(6)$ has two spinor representations that are respectively the fundamental and anti-fundamental representations of $SU(4)$, and I think these two spinor representations are also connected by a linear representation of $SO(6)$. Can anyone also show me this explicitly?

As for the projective representations of $SO(N)\times Z_2^T$, because $SO(N)$ has a spinor representation and $Z_2^T$ can also have a nontrivial projective representation where $g^2=-1$ (known as Kramers doublet in physics), the classification should be at least $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$. I think this is the full answer for odd $N$. For even $N$, because $SO(N)$ has a $Z_2$ center that may have nontrivial interplay with $Z_2^T$, the classification of projective representations may become $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$. But I am not sure how to pin this down.

By the way, it is known that $H^2(SO(N)\times Z_2^T,U(1))=Z_2^2$ for $N=2$ and $N=3$.

Comment: After thinking more, I believe the answer is that the projective representations of $SO(N)$ are classified by $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and the projective representations of $SO(N)\times Z_2^T$ are classified by $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$. The first statement was actually proved in arXiv 1206.2642. The second statement is based on a simple observation that rules out the possibility that the $Z_2$ center of $SO(2N)$ will contribute one more projective representation class.

Comment: Suppose the interplay between the $Z_2$ center and $Z_2^T$ does give a projective representation class, then this class has Kramers doublet under a new anti-unitary action: $Z_2\times Z_2^T$. Notice one can always choose the representation such that the actions of $Z_2$ and $Z_2^T$ commute without changing the projective representation class. With this choice, the Kramers doublet under $Z_2\times Z_2^T$ must have $Z_2$ acting twice to give a $-1$. But this is precisely the spinor! Therefore, the interplay between the $Z_2$ center and $Z_2^T$ does not give a new projective representation class.